# How can I embed buttons to my message using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, modulenotfounderror, discord-buttons

I am making a discord bot using discord.py (with slash commands), but I am stuck on embedding buttons to my message. I can send the messages fine but once I try to put embeds there is always an error.

I've tried using:
`from discord_components import Button`

But here's the error message:

`from discord_components import Button`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'`

I've looked into many SO questions but most of the answers don't work (ModuleNotFoundError) or do not support slash commands

Note: if it helps, I'm using replit as my IDE.

Comment: `discord.py` has built-in support for buttons, there's no need to install a third-party library for this. "there is always an error" is not very useful to us to help you figure out the issue. Also - replit is not an IDE, and you shouldn't run bots on replit. It causes a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your import might be wrong, try this.

```
from discord.ui import Button, View
```